# A/B testing on a news site to improve relevance

Tags: algorithm, testing

If you were running a news site that created a list of 10 top news stories, and you wanted to make tweaks to your algorithm and see if people liked the new top story mix better, how would you approach this?

Simple Click logging in the DB associated with the post entry?

A/B testing where you would show one version of the algorithm togroup A and another to group B and measure the clicks?

What sort of characteristics would you base your decision on as to whether the changes were better?

Answer (score 1):

A/B test seems a good start, and randomize the participants.  You'll have to remember them so they never see both.

You could treat it like a behavioral psychology experiment, do a T-Test etc...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to monitoring number of clicks, it might also be helpful to monitor how long they look at the story they clicked on.  It's more complicated data, but provides another level of information.  You would then not only be seeing if the stories you picked out grab the user's attentions, but also that the stories are able to keep it.

You could do statistical analysis (i.e. T-test like Tim suggested), but you probably won't get low enough of a standard deviation on either measure to prove significance.  Although, it won't really matter: all you need is for one of the algorithms to have a higher average number of clicks and/or time spent.  No need to fool around with hypothesis testing, hopefully.

Of course, there is always the option of simply asking the user if the recommendations were relevant, but that may not be feasible for your situation.